# How to initialize Global State like the MongoDB Serializer Registry in C# Azure Functions?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions

We're using the MongoDB Driver for C#/.NET in Azure Functions. To use custom serializers, the driver requires "registering" custom serializers with a "Global Registry", which apparently should be done at application startup, and independently of any particular function.

With this and other cross-cutting concerns, are there any techniques that can be used in Azure Functions which are supported or recommended by the Azure Functions Team?  I've seen requests in UserVoice for these things, and saw that the Azure functions team had started trying to add support for enabling DI/IOC patterns for functions, but don't know what the current standing is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the "official" way to accomplish this, but I think you can just put your initialization code in the script file before the function definition. That code will be executed once per Function App instance.

For instance the following function

```
static DateTime Now() => DateTime.Now;
static DateTime now = Now();

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(now.ToString());
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

will print the same date/time on subsequent executions, because `now` is only initialized once.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really a good solution because you'd have to choose one function to put it in.  Then, you'd have no assurance that the function would be executed before all the other functions that might reference it.  It's worth noting that a pattern like this could be used by simply putting similar code in a shared assembly which is what we're doing today.  However, I am hoping that the Functions team has found (or recently created) a simpler and more native mechanism/convention for enabling "Azure Function Runtime Startup Code".

Comment: Indeed, if you have multiple functions, you can share initialization code and call it before each function.

Comment: A first class mechanism for doing startup actions is tracked by this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/281